Oracle DB function to display with date manipulations
I have created a PL SQL function to calculate amount based of rates stored in the database for different period, The function is supposed to iterate through given month and get the rate of each month and do calculation for all months and obtain the total amount for all month as the result.
Unfortunately the function display different results when run in different computer with different data format. Could i be missing the calculation of months in the logic?
This is the PL/SQL function to calculate amount based on different rate stored in Database declare the function and the amount it accepts
For instance  in this function the submission date is today 12 July 2024 and months is 7 it is supposed to iterate in the loop for 7 monthes but in some cases it iterate 7 months, others 6 months and other 4 months. what will i be missing the logic? kindly assist
``FUNCTION of_calc_function(ad_submissiondate IN DATE,  as_type IN VARCHAR,  as_group IN VARCHAR, an_months IN NUMBER,an_tax IN NUMBER, an_result OUT NUMBER, as_message OUT VARCHAR ) RETURN NUMBER IS`
Declaration of variables required for calculation given the request submission date and the month required to iterate
ld_date                            DATE; 
ld_maxdate                      DATE; 
ln_rate                            NUMBER(10,4);
 ln_pn                        NUMBER(30,2); 
ln_pn_supprt                 NUMBER(30,2);
 ln_amount                       NUMBER(30,2); 
ln_spoint              NUMBER(30,2);
 ls_message                   VARCHAR2(4000); 
ld_pn_sdate                  DATE; 
ln_totval                    NUMBER(38,18); 
ln_totval_support            NUMBER(38,18); 
ln_months                    NUMBER; 
ld_datesub  DATE; 
BEGIN
ln_pn := 0;
ln_totval := 0;
ln_totval_support := 0;
ln_amount   := an_tax;
ln_months  := an_months;  
ld_datesub :=trunc(to_date(ad_submissiondate,'dd/mm/yyyy'));
--Minus the month acceptance from the function to get the start date to start  penalty calculation ld_pn_sdate:=trunc(to_date(ADD_MONTHS(ld_datesub,-ln_months),'dd/mm/yyyy'));

The following block is to select the maximim valid date from rate table and specific rates, then Iterates from the current month to the last valid date to get the amount

SELECT TRUNC(MAX(Fromdate))
INTO ld_maxdate
FROM RATES_TABLE
WHERE type=as_type and group =as_group;  
 ----    
FOR li_index  IN  1 .. ln_months 
LOOP

 ld_date :=to_date(ADD_MONTHS(ld_pn_sdate, li_index), 'dd/mm/yyyy');   ---start  compute penalty from next month after startdate 
 
    --get  rates for the dates 
IF TO_DATE(ld_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') >=TO_DATE(ld_maxdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy')   THEN
  SELECT tr, lsp
  INTO   ln_rate, ln_spoint
  FROM   RATES_TABLE
  WHERE  TO_DATE(Fromdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') = TO_DATE(ld_maxdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
              AND type=as_type and group =as_group;
ELSE
  SELECT tr, lsp
  INTO   ln_rate, ln_spoint
  FROM   RATES_TABLE
  WHERE TO_DATE(Fromdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') <= TO_DATE(ld_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND TRUNC(VALIDTO) >= TO_DATE(ld_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
             AND type=as_type AND group =as_group;
END IF; 

ln_pn_supprt    := ln_spoint;
ln_pn        := ln_amount*ln_rate*0.01;

ln_totval:=ln_totval+ln_pn;
ln_totval_support:=ln_totval_support+ln_pn_supprt;


END LOOP;  

   -- Pick the highest value of the two The higher of ln_totval and ln_totval_support
IF ln_totval <   ln_totval_support THEN
   ln_totval  :=  ln_totval_support;
END IF;

   an_result :=  ln_totval;
END of_calc_function;`


You should be able to get rid of all the loops and perform the calculation (much more efficiently) in a single SQL statement using aggregation.

Apart from that, ld_pn_sdate is never set in your code so at the moment it will not do anything and group is a reserved word so you cannot use it as an identifier.

You haven't give any sample data or expected output but you may be able to simplify the procedure to something like fiddle.

NEVER use TO_DATE on a value that is already a date.
ld_datesub :=trunc(to_date(ad_submissiondate,'dd/mm/yyyy'));

Should, assuming ad_submissiondate is named as such because it is the DATE data-type, be:
ld_datesub :=trunc(ad_submissiondate);

Similarly:
WHERE TO_DATE(Fromdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') <= TO_DATE(ld_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')

Should be:
WHERE TRUNC(Fromdate) <= TRUNC(ld_date)

and
TRUNC(VALIDTO) >= TO_DATE(ld_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')

should be:
TRUNC(VALIDTO) >= TRUNC(ld_date)

and anywhere else you use TO_DATE the TO_DATE either needs removing or replacing with TRUNC (if you are intending on removing the time component from the date).

Thank you very much, this worked. my problem was solved after the modification. Thank you very much
